# What is the difference between BO universes and Cognos cubes?

Tags: business-intelligence, business-objects, cognos

I'm currently trying to understand the mechanics behind BO and Cognos and to understand a bit more deeply how it actually works to start a BI project.

On the side on tradiationnal BI tools, i have trouble seeing the difference (other than the names) between the universes in Bo and the cubes .

Is there a real difference?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BO Universe is a metadata layer. You query it - you query database.
In addition to similar metadata layer Cognos BI has two types of cubes. Cube is Data in dimensional structure. With Dimensions and Measures. In addition to basic measure's values it contains aggregates for higher levels of every dimensions.

1. Transformer Cube. Contains all data inside cube file. You even don't need a database to query it.
2. Using Dynamic Cube technology you load data into memory and make calculations there. You still need a database, but should be faster. If you have enough memory.

Comment: Just a quick addition to this excellent response.  A BO universe is equivalent to a Cognos package.